# The Android Application crashes after I use ImageButtons, previously I used drawable shapes and it was working fine

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-drawable, android-imagebutton

The Android Application crashes after I use ImageButtons, previously I used drawable shapes and it was working fine.

**activity_app_list.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.smartcarassistant.AppListActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/appListTextview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Let me Assist You..."
        android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_light"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">
        <ImageButton
            android:contentDescription="Travel With Weather"
            android:id="@+id/buttonNotification"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_background"
            android:fontFamily="@font/cherry_cream_soda"
            android:src="@drawable/notifications"
            />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/buttonNotification"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:text="Manage">
            </TextView>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/buttonNotification"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:text="Notifications">
            </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">
        <ImageButton
            android:contentDescription="Travel With Weather"
            android:id="@+id/buttonMonthlyExpenses"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_background"
            android:src="@drawable/expense"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/buttonMonthlyExpenses"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:text="Monthly Expense">
            </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">
        <ImageButton
            android:contentDescription="Travel With Weather"
            android:id="@+id/buttonMoodyMusicPlayer"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_background"
            android:src="@drawable/music"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/buttonMoodyMusicPlayer"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:text="Moody Music">
            </TextView>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/buttonMoodyMusicPlayer"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:text="Player">
            </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

           <ImageButton
               android:contentDescription="Travel With Weather"
            android:id="@+id/buttonMileage"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_background"
               android:src="@drawable/mileage"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/buttonMileage"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:text="Mileage">
            </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

           <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonTravelWithWeather"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_background"
               android:contentDescription="Travel With Weather"
               android:src="@drawable/weather"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/buttonTravelWithWeather"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:text="Travel With">
            </TextView>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/buttonTravelWithWeather"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:text="Weather">
            </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

          <ImageButton
              android:contentDescription="Travel With Weather"
            android:id="@+id/buttonHelpDesk"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_background"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
              android:src="@drawable/helpdesk"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/buttonHelpDesk"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:text="HelpDesk">
            </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">


        <ImageButton
            android:contentDescription="Travel With Weather"
            android:id="@+id/buttonExploreAroundme"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circle_background"
            android:src="@drawable/explore"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/buttonExploreAroundme"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:text="Explore Around">

            </TextView>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/buttonExploreAroundme"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:text="ME">
            </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**AppListActivity.java**

```
package com.smartcarassistant;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AppListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_list);

        final ImageButton btNotification=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.buttonNotification);
        final ImageButton btMonthlyExpenses=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.buttonMonthlyExpenses);

        btNotification.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent4=new Intent(AppListActivity.this,NotificationActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent4);
            }
        });
        btMonthlyExpenses.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent3=new Intent(AppListActivity.this,MonthlyExpensesActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent3);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The code was fine as long as I was using shape backgrounds as icons for buttons, but when I switched to `ImageButton` it crashes immediately after openeing.

Comment: please add Error Log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was solved! I searched for it, and I got to know that some caches were responsible for it. After Cleaning the project, Invalidating Caches and restarting everything was fine.

Thank You all!

Answer (score 1):

first of all remove all "android:src=" line from every ImageButton in xml file

then in app level build.gradle file add these line in defaultConfig block

```
  defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

then sync project

then in onCreate of your activity add this line:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
```

then set image in activity class like this

```
btNotification.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.notification));
```